# styling of a textField's inputAssistantItem bar

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar

Is there a way to set the `backgroundColor` of the bar that contains the [inputAssistantItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputassistantitem) elements? (the bar that contains the "next" button in the image):

[image]

Also, is it possible to add a UILabel (like a title) to the bar?

Comment: I suggest you use a InputAccesoryView instead, this will allow you to use a custom view

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic I was thinking about it too, but I really just need the background color, it would save me some coding (yeah, I know I'm being lazy, but it's friday)

Comment: the code provided in the UITextInputAssistantItem interface doesnt help.. don't be lazy is not much code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I suggest you use inputAccessoryView** as it is a UIView you can just do pretty much everything you want with it.

I opened the *"UITextInput.h"* file and there seems to be no way to achieve what you want as the object does not give you the tools.

This is the code I found

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED @interface UITextInputAssistantItem : NSObject

/// Default is YES, controls if the user is allowed to hide the shortcuts bar. Does not influence the built in auto-hiding logic.
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL allowsHidingShortcuts;
/// Contains UIBarButtonItemGroups that should be displayed in the leading position on the keyboard's assistant bar.
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSArray<UIBarButtonItemGroup *> *leadingBarButtonGroups;
/// Contains UIBarButtonItemGroups that should be displayed in the trailing position on the keyboard's assistant bar.
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSArray<UIBarButtonItemGroup *> *trailingBarButtonGroups;

@end
```

**BAD POSSIBLE SOLUTION** could be checking the superview of the buttons you create until you find the toolbar and then trying to change what you want. I honestly recommend you **NOT TO DO THIS**.